# How to drop column by value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have df with two columns named the same thing.

df:

```
type     type
1        default
2        default
```

How do I drop the entire column where value = `default`?

New df looks like this:

```
type
1
2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc` and select them:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.eq('default').any(0)]  # ~df.eq('default').all(0)  # Stricter.
print (df)
   type
0     1
1     2
```

You can't use `drop`, `filter`, or any other idiomatic column removal technique because the column names are the same. Your only option is boolean selector based methods.

Comment: @RustyShackleford Thanks for that, I only need +56 for 100K now.

Answer (score 1):

How about a different approach, let's rename the columns instead.

```
df.columns = ['column_1', 'column_2']
```

And now, if we want to delete a column, we can choose the specific column.

```
df.drop(columns='column_2', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Fair enough, but sometimes it may not be obvious whether col_1 or col_2 has the "default" values. How do you handle this case in the general sense?

Comment: Well, given the limited information in @RustyShackleford's question, it seemed like he knew which column he wanted to remove, and that the repeated column name was his main hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `index` of the column you want, then just call `df.iloc[:,index]`
Some documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.